# SQL SELECT query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I need to get ssn and email that matches latest timestamp for each person, that is each person can have many emails with different timestamps, I need to get most recent.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT SSN, EMAIL 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE TIMESTAMP IN (SELECT TIMESTAMP 
                    FROM TABLE1
                    WHERE SSN IN ('111111111', '222222222', '333333333')       
                    ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
```

This gives me only one result instead of three. I tried to look for "FOR" statement but it seems it's been used only in stored procedures. Presumably, I have issue with inner select statement, I would be very thankful if you can shed some light to this issue. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using window fuctions?

```
select t1.ssn, t1.email
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ssn order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
      where SSN in ('111111111', '222222222', '333333333')
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: great solution! though I don't really know row_number and partition commands, guess its time learn about them, thank you for quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its a simple soultion where the records are fetched based on the latest timestamp for each person

```
select ssn, email
from table1 a
where timestamp = (Select max(timestamp) from table1 where ssn = a.ssn)
```

Comment: Code only answers are low quality and candidates for deletion, there should be at least 1 or 2 sentences explaining how you are answering the question and how this answers that question.